# Conditional formatting with several conditions depending on different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I currently have a table in excel that looks like

[image: this].

The table shows four projects, each with three stages with each having an expected and actual start date for that stage.

I want to create a corresponding table that shows a colour in each phase for each project in alignment with the following rules:

1- If there is no actual date for a phase and the projected date is **after** today's date then the cell is grey.
2- If there is no actual date for a phase and the projected date is **before** today's date then the cell is red (overdue).
3- If there is an actual date and a projected date, and the actual date is **on or before** the projected date then the cell is green.
4- If there is an actual date and a projected date and the actual date is **after** the projected date the cell is red.

This is an example of what the table should look like given the above data:
[image: This]

I know that I need to do something with conditional formatting but I'm not quite sure how to combine all four rules and duplicate the formulas across the whole table.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like that would get overly complex, trying to shove all that logic into conditional formatting. Might be easier to put all that logic in a formula in your table `B10:E12`, have it spit out some result (e.g. `RED`, `GREEN`, `GREY`) and do a conditional formatting on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the bottom table set up the same way as the top one, with the city names on the y axis and then, starting in B10, use a formula such as:

```
=IF(AND(C3<>"",B3<>"",C3>B3),2,
IF(AND(C3<>"",B3<>"",C3<=B3),1,
IF(AND(C3="",B3<TODAY()),2,
IF(AND(C3="",B3>TODAY()),0))))
```

Then you can set up a conditional formatting rule that hightlights 0 as grey, 1 as green, and 2 as red. You can do this in one Graded Color Scale conditional formatting rule, or you can create three separate rules to do the same thing and also format the numbers themselves so that they are the same color as the background (so you won't see them).